# block URL directory or file in cloud armor

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an issue, my website folder can be view publicly. example a.com/folder1/folder2/ and public can see what inside the folder. is the any policy i can applied in the cloud armor to prevent this. cause some folder contain sensitive information.

Thank you for your time

add url block, but it block permanently, when user login it also blocked